# brew install : undefined method `desc'

Tags: homebrew

I try to install some softs with homebrew.

But I get the following :

```
>>>brew install irssi
Error: undefined method `desc' for Formulary::Formulae::Irssi:Class
Please report this bug:
http://git.io/brew-troubleshooting
/nfs/zfs-student-3/users/2013_paris/vmonteco/.brew/Library/Formula/irssi.rb:2:in `<class:Irssi>'
/nfs/zfs-student-3/users/2013_paris/vmonteco/.brew/Library/Formula/irssi.rb:1:in `load_file'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/formulary.rb:92:in `module_eval'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/formulary.rb:92:in `load_file'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/formulary.rb:82:in `klass'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/formulary.rb:71:in `get_formula'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/formulary.rb:200:in `factory'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/extend/ARGV.rb:16:in `block in formulae'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/extend/ARGV.rb:16:in `map'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/extend/ARGV.rb:16:in `formulae'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/cmd/install.rb:42:in `install'
/usr/local/Library/brew.rb:135:in `<main>'
```

I tried to do `brew update` and retry, but I got the same issue.
I tried to use brew doctor but I get dozens (hundreds?) of the following :

```
undefined method `desc' for Formulary::Formulae::<something>::Class
```

How could I fix this? Even a workaround would be fine.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.  Try https://apple.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1):

An undefined method of `desc` indicates that your Homebrew is outdated.  The recommended solution is to [update your Homebrew](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/41882) version with:

```
$ brew update -v
```

Using the `-v` flag will provide additional output. Run the command [twice](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/Troubleshooting.md#troubleshooting), and then attempt to install a formula again.